# What is the difference between 16bit 48000hz with dvd quality and without dvd quality?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, audio, sound-card, playback

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7xwX.png]

As the attached image, 
when I plugged Yamaha pjp-20ur on my Windows 8.1 notebook, 
the default format has two option:

- '16bit, 48000Hz'                  =>seems to be default
- '16bit, 48000Hz (DVD Quality)'

what is the difference between the two option?

the reason why I ask this question:

- first option: playing system test sound --> no sound
- second option: playing system test sound --> OK

and when I open webRTC sample page on chrome

sample page: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/multi/

and select Yamaha pjp-20ur

- first default format option: sound came out from the default playback
- second default format option: OK

so what's the difference between the two default format?
They have same bit depth and same sample rate, one option has note 'DVD quality' and another doesn't.

Comment: I guess you have 2 drivers

Comment: If you only have 2 sample rates to choose from, one of them ought to be 44100, the other 48000. Something has gone screwy with the driver, but I'm not sure what. Picture of the full playback choices on a high-end device - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff25S.png The description, btw, is just a 'consumer' explanation of what the different standards are usually used for, they're not in themselves a vital part of each standard.